# Language Pack not working

Tags: language, translation

I download latest translated WordPress pack and wish to change my website to my language. I uploaded language folder to wp-content and adding

```
define ('WPLANG', 'bn_BD')
```

to wp-config file but no language appear on Site language option. Here is the language folder location screenshot. Anything new add in 4.2.2? Need help to change the language..

http://s22.postimg.org/pse5hdc01/site_bengali.png

Answer (score 0):

now, you can change the language in the back-end

in the general configuration page, at the bottom of the page

Comment: That is what i said, no new pack appear on General>Site Language Option...